# How can I subtract two values which I have got from a .txt file

Tags: python, csv

So far I have managed to print out certain parts of the `.txt` file in Python however I cannot figure out how to subtract the amount paid from my total amount and then add up the outstanding value from each column.

```
import csv

FILE_NAME = "paintingJobs.txt" #I use this so that the file can be used easier
COL_HEADERS = ['Number', 'Date', 'ID', 'Total', 'Status', 'Paid']
NUM_COLS = len(COL_HEADERS)#This will insure that the header of each column fits into the length of the data

# read file once to determine maximum width of data in columns
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # determine the maximum width of the data in each column
    max_col_widths = [len(col_header) for col_header in COL_HEADERS]
    for columns in reader:
        for i, col in enumerate(columns):
            if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
                max_col_widths[i] = max(max_col_widths[i], len(repr(col)))
    # add 1 to each for commas
    max_col_widths = [col_width+1 for col_width in max_col_widths]

# read file second time to display its contents with the headers
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # display justified column headers
    print(' ' + ' '.join(col_header.ljust(max_col_widths[i])
                            for i, col_header in enumerate(COL_HEADERS)))
    # display justified column data
    for columns in reader:
        if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
            print(columns)`
```

This is the result so far:

```
 Number   Date          ID      Total   Status  Paid  
['E5345', '22/09/2015', 'C106', '815', 'A', '400']
['E5348', '23/09/2015', 'C109', '370', 'A', '200']
['E5349', '25/09/2015', 'C110', '480', 'A', '250']
['E5353', '28/09/2015', 'C114', '272', 'A', '200']
['E5355', '29/09/2015', 'C116', '530', 'A', '450']
['E5363', '01/10/2015', 'C124', '930', 'A', '500']
['E5364', '02/10/2015', 'C125', '915', 'A', '800']
['E5367', '03/10/2015', 'C128', '427', 'A', '350']
['E5373', '10/10/2015', 'C134', '1023', 'A', '550']
```

What i want to do is add a new column which is the difference of the total and the paid

Comment: Does the question - in principle - have anything to do with that blob of code, or can the nature of the problem be decoupled from your actual program? If so, please do so, and provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Or in other words: the title is such a simple question, why is the question so complicated?

Comment: Ok so far i have managed to get csv to display it from a .txt file now i want it to subtract the 6th column from the 4th column

Comment: I cant find a way to shorten down the code without info being missing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data is being stored as strings. Have you tried changing them to integers? You would do it like this. Suppose we have:

```
x="1"

y="2"
```

You can convert them to integers like this.

```
x=int(x)

y=int(x)
```

Then you should have no problem adding them.

Comment: Even if i do this i still dont know how to add a new column which is the difference of the total and the paid.

Answer (score 0):

I've destroyed your column width sizing approach, but here is a simple change to the last for block in your file that should do what you want. Just replace everything after `# display justified column data`.

```
for row in reader:
    total = int(row[3])
    paid = int(row[5])
    if 'A' in row[4] and paid < total:
        print('\t'.join((_ for _ in row)), total - paid)
```

Making the Total and Paid amounts integers is pretty simple, finding a way to display the new data is a little more work.

Comment: I did as you said however I have encountered an I/O error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.